# Add pythonhelper to a MacVim statusline in vim-powerline

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I would like to add [pythonhelper](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=435) to [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/), using MacVim.

There is an issue that discusses this [on github](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/issues/90), but although the issue is closed the resolution was not clear.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: As the github issue discusses, at the moment customization of powerline is something of a hack. You have to edit the source code like [this](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/issues/90#issuecomment-4031652) user did. I hope someone figures this out for you though and answers!